# Is voltage always be holded by 1 coloumb of charge carrying electrons?

Tags: electrostatics

We know that voltage is nothing but the energy hold by $1\,\text C$ of charge and  $1\,\text C=6.25\cdot10^{18}$ electrons, so does that mean whatever the value of potential is, that will always be holded by this much electrons only?

If this is true then please consider the following case: Suppose we have a resistor of 5 ohm and a battery of 20 volts, this means that $6.25\cdot10^{18}$ electrons have 20 joules of energy and the current by $V=IR$  is the $I$ is 4 ampere and we know that $I=ne/t$ and let's say time is 1 second  so by that $n=2.5\cdot10^{19}$ electrons not $6.25\cdot10^{18}$ so how is it true?

And if this is the case then the resistor can have more potential than the mentioned potential of battery.

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential difference between two points is the work done per unit charge when we move a charge between those points i.e. it is the work divided by the charge.

So suppose we move a charge $Q$ and the work done is $W$, then the potential difference is given by:

$$ V = \frac{W}{Q} \tag{1}$$

The charge $Q$ can be any charge. It could be a single electron with a charge $Q = -e$, or some huge charge of many coulombs $Q = 10^6\mathrm{C}$, or a unit charge $Q=1\mathrm{C}$. The work would be different for the three charges but when we take the ratio $V = W/Q$ we will get the same value of $V$ every time.

The reason we so often talk about a unit charge is that for a unit charge $Q = 1\mathrm{C}$ and our equation (1) simplifies to:

$$ V = W $$

So using a unit charge is convenient only because it simplifies the equation. There is no fundamental reason a unit charge has to be used.

Comment: thank you so much sir....you really helped me a lot.

Comment: It would be so nice of you if you can elaborate what did you mean by saying"the work would be different for three charges but when we take the ratio V=W/Q we will get the same value of V every time"

Answer (score 0):

A current of 4 amps indicates the 4 coulombs of charge are transferred each second. Each of those dissipates 20 joules of energy in the resistor.  What's the problem?

Comment: if each of those dissipated 20 joules then it would be 4X20=80 joules but our resistor only needs 20 J.so how is that even possible?

Comment: Volts is Joules per Coulomb. Each coulomb dropping through a 20 volt change dissipates 20 Joules of energy.  The resistor does not “need” 20 Joules; it receives 80 J each second. (Power = amps x volts)

Comment: Let me clarify what do i mean by "need".